# c 2d array static initialization with preserved size

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, static-allocation

similar to 1D array declaration :

```
char arr[]={[0 ... RESERVED_CHARS-1]=' ',[RESERVED_CHARS]='\0'};
```

please advice how / if possible to declare such 2D array ?

```
#define SAY_MAX_MSG_LEN 6
#define REP_MAX_MSG_LEN 8

char *var_msg_out[][3]={\
    {" Say ",[][0 ... SAY_MAX_MSG_LEN+1]=' ','\0'},\
    {" Reply ",[][0 ... REP_MAX_MGS_LEN+1]=' ','\0'}\
};
snprintf(var_msg_out[0][1],SAY_MAX_MSG_LEN,"hello");
printf("%s",var_msg_out[0]);
```

Thanks !

Comment: *"similar to 1D array declaration "*, this is valid C for 1D array ?

Comment: @PiotrS.: I was surprised too.  Apparently the [...] is a GCC extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html (it works in Clang too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part of what you have is this:

```
char *var_msg_out[][3]={
    {" Say ",[][0 ... SAY_MAX_MSG_LEN+1]=' ','\0'},
              ^ ???
```

There is a fundamental issue here: the element after " Say " is a `char*`, yet you are trying to assign to it as if it were a char array.  The two are not the same thing: your `char*` can point to a literal string (like " Say ") with no problem, but you cannot initialize its characters because there is nothing to initialize--only a pointer!

You can fix it this way:

```
struct foo {
    const char* x;
    char y[100];
    const char* z;
};

struct foo var_msg_out[]={
    {" Say ", {[0 ... SAY_MAX_MSG_LEN+1]=' '}, ""},
    {" Reply ", {[0 ... REP_MAX_MSG_LEN+1]=' '}, ""}
};
```

Comment: You're right on my (briefly written) example mistake.
But, solution of allocating char y[100]; is not desired.
I'm looking for specific reasons to align the solution as for 1D example.

Comment: No such solution is possible, because multi-dimensional arrays in C are never sparse nor jagged, meaning each dimension must have the same fixed length.  You can either set a fixed length as I have, or you can go back to using `char*` for the second column and allocate storage for it outside.  Either use `malloc()` or some stack-allocated pool of strings, and set the pointers in the second column of your matrix to point to those dynamically-sized arrays outside.